# Forward declare a constexpr variable template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr, variable-templates

I tried to forward-declare a `constexpr` variable template like this:

```
template<typename>
constexpr std::size_t iterator_category_value;
```

The goal was to document that every specialization should be `constexpr` but I have to admit that I never checked whether it was legal or not and g++ was happy with it. However, when I tried to compile this spinnet with clang++ instead, I got the following error:

> ```
> error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const std::size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long')
>     constexpr std::size_t iterator_category_value;
>                           ^
>                                                   = 0
> ```

The error makes sense, and removing `constexpr` makes it disappear, so that's not a real problem. However, I am curious now: does the standard allow such a `constexpr` forward declaration for a variable template or is it illegal? g++ and clang++ seem to disagree and I would like to know where I should submit a bug report if needed.

Both of them complain for a forward-declared `constepxr` variable which is not a variable template, so the variable template context seems to be what makes the compilers disagree.

Comment: The text of http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1712 implies that you cannot forward-declare it as `constexpr`, however I'm not quite sure how the std forbids it. A variable template does not looks like an *object declaration* to me.

Comment: OTOH, [dcl.dcl]p9 seems very general, and should apply to variable templates (=> variable templates are object declarations => `constexpr` requires initialization)

Comment: @dyp Btw., what do you mean by "now"? Aren't you compiling the most up to date sources currently available on Git?

Comment: @Columbo Not regularly :)

Comment: @dyp Yeah, a variable template declaration being an *object declaration* wasn't really obvious to me, hence the question :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the C++14 standard, it seems pretty clear that initialization is required.  From section 7.5.1 paragraph 9,

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration
>     declares the object as const.  Such an object shall have
>     literal type and shall be initialized.

As for the exact meaning of "object declaration", Section 7 paragraph 7 states:

> If the decl-specifier-seq contains no typedef specifier,
>     the declaration is called a function declaration if the
>     type associated with the name is a function type and
>     an object declaration otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Clang is correct. The *declaration* of a variable template is an object declaration ([dcl.dcl]/9), hence it must provide an initializer as per [dcl.constexpr]/9:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as `const`. **Such an object […] shall be
>   initialized.**

There is effectively no way of "forward" declaring an object as `constexpr` in the first place, though; If `constexpr` is applied to the declaration of a variable, it shall be a definition ([dcl.constexpr]/1).

Comment: [Is something changed lately?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb1d8ebe90a2bc11)

Comment: Just a code containing discussed case. It contains forward declaration of `constexpr` variable template, but compiles fine.

Comment: @Orient You do realize you're compiling with the compiler that is bugged in this respect?

Comment: Yes, but this change introduced in the near past, I think. Probably intentionally. But maybe not though.

Comment: @Orient Well, GCC only started supporting all the features used from 5.2 onwards, and that version already spuriously compiles this fine.