# Is this method to forward declare template variable legal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, forward-declaration, template-variables

In the code bellow is listed example of forward declaration of constant template variables which compiles on both clang and gcc:

```
template<class T>
extern const T value;
template<class T>
const T value= 0;

auto test = value<int>;

template<class T>
extern const T value2;
template<class T>
constexpr T value2 =0;

auto test2 = value2<int>;

template<class T>
extern const T value3;
template<class T>
inline constexpr T value3 =0;

auto test3 = value3<int>;
```

Nevertheless if I declare the variables non const, gcc produces a linker error:`undefined reference to value4<int>` and `undefined symbol value5<int>`, but clang accepts the code:

```
template<class T>
extern T value4;
template<class T>
T value4= 0;

auto test4 = value4<int>; //gcc linker error

template<class T>
extern T value5;
template<class T>
inline T value5=0;

auto test5 = value5<int>; //gcc linker error
```

Initially I was confident all those uses cases where standard compliant. But because gcc produces a linker error for the last two cases, I was wondering if any of these forward declarations were legal? Is gcc wrong or am I on a *no diagnostic required* error? May a forward declaration followed by an inline definition of template variables as `value3` or `value5` in multiple translation unit cause odr violation?

[Linking phase error demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af8c33f258ab57c7)

---

<sub>Note: In this [answers to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33197817/5632316) it seems they have overlooked the possibility to declare the variable as an extern const.</sub>

Comment: Can you show the actual code and what is in which file? Or is this exactly the code that fails with clang?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Nothing more than that, maybe you can add `int main(){}` if you don't like the undefined reference to main error.

Comment: Well, godbolt accepts the code, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Because godblot does not perform the link phase.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You can see the error [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af8c33f258ab57c7)

Comment: Good point... I saw it while playing a little bit more. Still, there is no concrete symbol, so gcc is probably right.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher What do you mean by *concrete symbol*?

Comment: The symbol itself, that should be "exported" (as the extern would imply), but then I suppose "Unless a variable template was explicitly specialized or explicitly instantiated, it is implicitly instantiated when a specialization of the variable template is used." this would mean gcc should have created the symbol? it was used int he assignment and should have been created there, shouldn't it?

Comment: Seems [bug 83342](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83342).

Comment: @xskxzr Thank you.